# How to set message bus message type to JSON?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am using the HelloTextGoogleCast sample's receiver.html.  But I need to set the message bus's message type to JSON.

Here is part of it.

```
    // create a CastMessageBus to handle messages for a custom namespace
    window.messageBus =
      window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
          'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld');
```

I tried this right after the above code.  But it does not work:

```
 window.messageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`window.messageBus =
      window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
          'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld',      cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);`

Comment: Hi Ali, i am using v3 on receiver side i wrote a code but can't able to receive messages, can you please help me how to receive the messages using v3. my code is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972342/unable-to-receive-messages-from-receiver-side-using-google-chrome-cast-receiver